# Formula in Named range returns incorrect result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I try to match rows by multiple criteria.

I've given the formula below and [sample file link](https://easyupload.io/1aajrb).

The Named Reference Formula returns `incorrect` result in cell B34 i.e., "1".

The Individual Cell Reference Formula (replacing named reference to individual cell reference for ex. Load to "E5") returns `correct` result in A34 i.e., "0".

How to make the Named Reference Formula to work correctly?

[image: Screenshot]

Named Reference Formula:

```
=(--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZFIX",Load),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZTEN",Load),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZDIL",Load),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("End",Load),0),1,0)+--IF(LEFT(f_CustomerNumber1,LEN(f_CustomerNumber1))=ZFIX_Customer1,1,0)*IF(OR(Indicator= "F",Indicator= "T",Indicator = "D"),1,0)*IF(OR(DiscLevel = "",DiscLevel = "Mat"),1,0))
```

Individual Cell Reference Formula:

```
=(--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZFIX",DataSheet!E5),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZTEN",DataSheet!E5),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZDIL",DataSheet!E5),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("End",DataSheet!E5),0),1,0)+--IF(LEFT(f_CustomerNumber1,LEN(f_CustomerNumber1))=DataSheet!W5,1,0)*IF(OR(DataSheet!B5= "F",DataSheet!B5= "T",DataSheet!B5= "D"),1,0)*IF(OR(DataSheet!Q5= "",DataSheet!Q5= "Mat"),1,0))
```

Comment: What does the DataSheet look like? From looking at what you have provided "LOAD" is a NamedRange which is a Fixed Reference (will not adjust when copied) whereas DataSheet!E5 is a Relative Reference (will adjust when copied).

Comment: `=(--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZFIX",INDEX(Load,ROW()-1)),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZTEN",INDEX(Load,ROW()-1)),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("ZDIL",INDEX(Load,ROW()-1)),0),1,0)+--IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("End",INDEX(Load,ROW()-1)),0),1,0)+--IF(LEFT(f_CustomerNumber1,LEN(f_CustomerNumber1))=INDEX(ZFIX_Customer1,ROW()-1),1,0)*IF(OR(INDEX(Indicator,ROW()-1)= "F",INDEX(Indicator,ROW()-1)= "T",INDEX(Indicator,ROW()-1) = "D"),1,0)*IF(OR(INDEX(DiscLevel,ROW()-1) = "",INDEX(DiscLevel,ROW()-1) = "Mat"),1,0))` - enter this in B2 and then copy down

Comment: @RetiredGeek. B column formula is spill type.

Comment: @SpectralInstance. Thanks. But I would like to understand why the Spill type function works differently.

Comment: Because you use the `OR()` function in your last 2 tests, and `OR()` is an aggregate function, i.e. when you use it on an entire range then you will only get one result back (NOT one result per row) so, in the case of both of your `OR()` functions, the result for each is 1 (and not a series of 1s or 0s); btw your original formula can be considerably shortened: `=(SUM(COUNTIF(DataSheet!E5,{"ZFIX","ZTEN","ZDIL","END"}))+N(f_CustomerNumber1&""=DataSheet!W5)*SUM(COUNTIF(DataSheet!B5,{"F","T","D"}))*SUM(COUNTIF(DataSheet!Q5,{"","Mat"})))`

Comment: Unless you want to amalgamate several `BYROW()`/`LAMBDA()` functions, you should _not_ try to make the above formula spill, since `COUNTIF()` is also an aggregate function

Comment: Spill function, using simple addition in lieu of `IFERROR`/`SEARCH`/`OR` functions: `=(Load="ZFIX")+(Load="ZTEN")+(Load="ZDIL")+(Load="END")+(""&f_CustomerNumber1=ZFIX_Customer1)*((Indicator= "F")+(Indicator= "T")+(Indicator = "D"))*((DiscLevel = "")+(DiscLevel = "Mat"))`